# How to make a Table where each cell is a list in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, list

The problem I am trying to solve is one where we have for example a network with 5 nodes. And each node can hold tokens {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H}.

I want to make a table such that we have the node identifiers on the left hand side. and tokens seen, tokens not seen and tokens held across the top.

I want to make it so each cell can hold not just one value but multiple values, therefore I think I'd need a list.

Any help would be appreciated. I have drawn an example of the table structure below.

```
 Tokens seen     Tokens not seen    Tokens held
```

1

2

3

4

5

Comment: Check out [cell arrays](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). For example, `t = {[1 3 4], [2 3]; 5, [5 1 2]}` creates a 2×2 cell array containing numeric vectors

Answer (score 0):

The cells of a MATLAB `table` can contain cell arrays:

```
% Initialise the table
t = table;
t.nodeID = {'node1'; 'node2'; 'node3'; 'node4'; 'node5'};
t.tokensSeen = repmat({[]}, 5, 1);
t.tokensNotSeen = repmat({[]}, 5, 1);
t.tokensHeld = repmat({[]}, 5, 1);

% Set individual cell values
t.tokensSeen{2} = {'A'};
t.tokensHeld{3} = {'B', 'C'};

% Retrieve cell values
ismember('A', t.tokensSeen{3})
```

and so on.

See the MATLAB help for tables and cell arrays for more information on working with these data types. You may also find the various set operations (such as `ismember`) helpful - search the help for 'set operations' to see more details.

Alternatively you could use the `Map` class, creating one Map for each of the three categories and using the node IDs as the map keys:

```
tokensSeen = containers.Map;
tokensSeen('node1') = {'A'};
tokensSeen('node2') = {'B', 'C'};
```

Again, the usage of `containers.Map` is described in the MATLAB help.